# selenium tests on safari

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to run my Selenium tests on Safari 11 browser and am unable to launch the browser. I have enabled the Remote automation option in Safari and am tried to launch the browser,But it didn't work as well. I have set up my driver as RemoteWebdriver and I get the error as below:

**Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.**

Can any one please help?

Comment: Please copy paste your code. It'll help to provide the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

@jyothi B please run following two commands

```
/usr/bin/safaridriver --enable
/usr/bin/safaridriver -p 0
```

and then start your tests.

Comment: I have enabled the safri driver and I have a shell script file for safari which has the following                                                                                        /usr/bin/safaridriver -p 7777 > ../safari.log.                                                                     I am running the above and have set my port as 7777 for safari browser. I still get the error message unable to instantiate webdriver.

Comment: This didn't do anything for me. WebDriverError: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 10063 ms

Comment: Please follow instructions given on this [site](https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/)